# laravel relationship not showing foreign key value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've created a relationship between two tables but when I call it shows the **id** instead of **foreign key**

My Unit model:

```
class Unit extends Model
{
   protected $table='units';
   public function unit_id()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Procurment_request::class,'unit_id','id');
   }
}
```

My Procurment Model:

```
class Procurment_request extends Model
{
    protected $table ='procurment_requests';
    public function unit_id(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Unit::class);
    }
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('show',function (){
    $result=Procurment_request::all();
    return $result;
});
```

And the result:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "quantity":1,
      ***"units_id":1***,
      "description":"adf",
      "requster":0,
      "checker":0,
      "approver":0,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null
   }
]
```

I want to show the name of Unit not the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change relation name to

```
class Procurment_request extends Model
{
    protected $table ='procurment_requests';

    public function unit(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Unit::class, 'units_id');
    }

}
```

And use

```
Route::get('show',function (){
    $result=Procurment_request::with('unit')->get();
    $result->map(function ($item) {
        $item->unit_name = $item->unit->unit_name;
        unset($item['unit']);
    });
    return $result;
});
```

Comment: I did now it says "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()"

Comment: still getting the id number instead of name

Comment: You must be get number and also `unit` and there here unit:name

Comment: sorry my bad I got the unit:name but it show's null          [{"id":1,"quantity":1,"units_id":1,"description":"adf","requster":0,"checker":0,"approver":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"unit":null}]

Comment: still the same result [{"id":1,"quantity":1,"units_id":1,"description":"adf","requster":0,"checker":0,"approver":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"account_name":null}]

Comment: Delete this part and show result `unset($item['unit']);`

Comment: [{"id":1,"quantity":1,"units_id":1,"description":"adf","requster":0,"checker":0,"approver":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"account_name":null,"unit":{"id":1,"unit_name":"a","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}]

Comment: Finally it worked thank you very much are sorry for the troubles.